# why my switch button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have switch button. when it's clicked one table should be visible, another one is hidden. but t doesn't work properly =(

here is fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/wgcwwht7/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        var switchBtn2 = document.getElementById('switch-flight2');

        $(switchBtn2).click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('checked');
            $('#deptbl2').toggleClass('hidden');
            $('#arrtbl2').toggleClass('visible');
        });
    });
```

```css
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
.visible{
    display: block;
}
.table-scroll > tbody > tr > td, .table > tfoot > tr > td{
    border-top: 0;
}
.table > tbody + tbody{
    border-top: 0;
}
.table tbody tr td, .table thead tr td{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
}

/*THEAD*/
.table-scroll thead tr td{
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;*/
}
.table-scroll > thead > tr > td span{
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
}


table.table-scroll {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
table.table-scroll thead, table.table-scroll tbody {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
table.table-scroll tbody {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 298px;
}
table.table-scroll thead tr {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    text-align: left;
}
table.table-scroll tbody tr td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.table-scroll tbody tr:first-child{
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.table-scroll tbody tr:first-child td, .table-scroll tbody tr:first-child td:nth-child(2){
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.table-scroll tbody tr td:nth-child(2){
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.table-scroll tbody tr td:nth-child(1){
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.table-scroll > tfoot > tr > td{
    padding: 10px 8px;
}
.table-scroll tfoot td{
    text-align: left;
}
.table-scroll tfoot td a{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


/*switch button*/
.switch-box{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 400px;
}
.switch-box span{
    width: 40%;
    height: 45px;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #333333;
}
.switch-box span.landing{
    text-align: right;
    background: url('img/plane_land.png') 53px -4px no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
}
.switch-box span.arriving{
    text-align: left;
    background: url('img/plane_arr.png') 58px -4px no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
}

.switch {
    width: 20%;
    height: 21px;
    margin: 12px 0;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.switch input {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.switch label {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: #00498B;
    border-radius: 40px;
    box-shadow:
        inset 0 3px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
        0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
.switch label:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: -8px; right: -8px; bottom: -8px; left: -8px;
    border-radius: inherit;

}
.switch label i {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: inherit;
    background: #b2ac9e; /* Fallback */
    background: linear-gradient(#f7f2f6, #b2ac9e);
    box-shadow:
        inset 0 1px 0 white,
        0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
        0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.switch label i:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -50%;
    margin-top: -12px;
    color: #666; /* Fallback */
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #bcb8ae, 0 -1px 0 #97958e;
}

.switch input:checked ~ label { /* Background */
    background: #00498B;
}

.switch input:checked ~ label i { /* Toggle */
    left: auto;
    right: -1%;
}

.switch input:checked ~ label i:before { /* On/off */
    content: "";
    right: 115%;
    color: #82a06a;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #afcb9b, 0 -1px 0 #6b8659;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-box">
    <span class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 landing">Прибытие</span>
    <div class="switch col-lg-2 col-md-2 no-padding">
        <input id="switch-flight2" type="checkbox">
        <label><i></i></label>
    </div>
    <span class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 arriving">Вылет</span>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 no-padding" id="deptbl2">
    <table class="table table-scroll">
        
        <tbody class="tb-row scroll-pane">
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            
            
        </tbody>
        
    </table>
</div>


<div id="arrtbl2" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 no-padding hidden">
    <table class="table table-scroll">
        
        <tbody class="tb-row scroll-pane">
            <tr>
                <td>7789</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1234</td>
                <td>13245</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1235213</td>
                <td>1235</td>
                <td>1325</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        
    </table>
</div>
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify jQuery as library in your fiddle.

Also, the jQuery plugin jScrollPane is missing. it works when I removed it.

```
//removed code
$(function()
{
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane( //jScrollPane is not found.
        {
            horizontalGutter: 30,
            verticalGutter: 30
        }
    );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wgcwwht7/3/

Comment: it doesn't work even if jscrollpane plugin included https://jsfiddle.net/wgcwwht7/8/

Comment: Open your browser web inspector. I'll see the error. Even though you have added the files, it still not finding the function jScrollPane(). If you comment out the jScrollPane, you will see that your switch button works properly

Answer (score 0):

Change `$` to `jQuery` and define it on top like, `var $ = jQuery;` if it doesn't work, call jQuery library from a cdn dir